# What if someone does not reply back my Salaam?

Tags: greetings

I had a quarrel with my friend. But, as I had a habbit of greeting her by saying Salaam. So, I did that. But she even after hearing me did not replied me back. I felt very bad.

So, are there any rulings in Islam when someone ignores your Salaam?

Comment: Then she has performed a sin.

Answer (score 1):

With some exceptions, replying to Salam is obligatory:

> #### وإذا حييتم بتحية فحيوا بأحسن منها أو ردوها إن الله كان على كل شيء حسيبا
>
> And when you are greeted with a greeting, greet [in return] with one better than it or [at least] return it [in a like manner]. Indeed, Allah is ever, over all things, an Accountant.
>
> <sup>— [Quran 4:86](http://quran.com/4/86)</sup>

If someone did not reply to you then:

- You should not be discouraged as you have done what was required of you and you will be rewarded for it. There are traditions that the angels would return your greeting. <sup>[طبراني](https://shamela.ws/book/1733/12391#p1) , [ابن السني](https://shamela.ws/book/13132/302#p1)</sup>
- You should advise the other person to reply and inform them of their obligation.
- You should forgive them \ waive your right upon them.  <sup>[الأذكار](https://shamela.ws/book/1956/257#p3)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

As a man when I give Salaam to a muslim woman, they're not required to respond, which is fine. Bearing this in mind, if a muslim man doesn't respond to my Salaam, well... I'm sure you can see where I am coming from  lol

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE. I strongly suggest you to take the [tour] and check our [help] for further information on how this site works. Why should it be fine if women don't respond your salam?

Answer (score 0):

Continue to greet them back with the same salam u till Allah blessings you

Answer (score -2):

Well, when I was a kid, my mama told me that if someone doesn't respond to your salaam , then Allah will take care of his jannah.